# can you use default and parameter constructor at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, class

I have been assigned to make a class using both default and parameter constructor but the thing is, is that even possible? I don't get how it can even work..both are supposed to assign values to variables

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142929/2310289

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? The form of the `new` expressions determines the constructor to be run.

Comment: @ScaryWombat that link doesn't discuss default constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowed from this answer from @bohemian

```
public class Person
    ...
    public Person() { 
        this("unknown", 0); // you can call another constructor 
    }

    public Person(String nm, int ag) {
        name = nm;  
        age = ag;
    }
    ...
}
```

In this example if the no-args constructor is called then `unknown` and `0` will be passed to the other constructor

Comment: There is no default constructor in that class.

Comment: Yeah, I should say `no-args` constructor

Answer (score 1):

When you define another constructor in your class, you do not get the "usual" default constructor (public and without arguments) anymore.

However, you can add it back in:

```
class MyClass{
   MyClass(String param){}  // custom constructor
   MyClass(){}              // bring back the non-arg one
}
```

Of course, when creating an object instance using `new` you have to choose which one to call (you cannot have both):

```
 MyClass instanceA = new MyClass("a string");
 MyClass instanceB = new MyClass();
```

The constructors can call each-other (using `this(parameters)`) or shared methods if there is common functionality in them that you want to keep in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't do that in Java, by definition.JLS §8.8.9, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9 says, "If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared." So as soon as you add any constructor declaration, even a no-arg constructor, you don't get a default constructor.